# Migrating a rails 2.3 app to use Bundler instead of config.gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

I have a rails 2.3.8 app that I'm trying to move to Heroku, which implies that I also need to migrate to bundler.

I've followed a number of steps that explain how (http://gembundler.com/rails23.html), but one gem (or at least it could be more I'm not sure yet) doesn't seem to be loaded.

The gem is "acts_as_taggable_on_steroids". I have a post model, which then has 'acts_as_taggable' declared.

When I run `rake db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_taggable' for # Class:0x1034acfa0
```

Ideas? Gemfile below:

**Gemfile**

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
gem "rails", "~>2.3.8"

gem "acts_as_taggable_on_steroids", :require => "acts_as_taggable", :git => "git://github.com/jviney/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids.git"
```

**EDIT** 
I do use (and have) 'acts_as_taggable' in the Post model. I used the `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids` gem for the functionality before the migration to Bundler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you run 'bundle check' first? and if that works 'bundle install'

Comment: yes. I actually started off without that field but added in thinking it might fix the problem. (it didn't)

Comment: Does it still throw the exact error without that field? If so I'd try gem "acts_as_taggable" before the steroids line

Comment: tried that too and no joy. I don't really understand, could it be something to do with a .gemspec file or something like that? +1 for continued help :) thanks!

Comment: no problem, never used Heroku, but used the bundler quite a bit for rails 3 stuff. If you're still getting undefined "acts_as_taggable" without the require field, are you sure you don't still have "acts_as_taggable" in one of your models?

Comment: yeah, I do use the acts_as_taggable in the Post model. Didn't have the problem without bundler. I need that gem for the tagging of posts.

Comment: is "acts_as_taggable" in gem list, the fact the issue has come up since you started using bundler makes me think that now the app is using the bundled gems, rather than the server gems this is the problem.

Comment: here is my gem list: acts_as_taggable (2.0.2)
acts_as_taggable_on_steroids (1.2)

Comment: Ok, gem list gives the server gems, are they both in bundle list

Comment: I'm flat out of ideas, sorry I couldn't help

Comment: when I run bundle package, none of the git gems are (that is, I use :git => ....) are listed. Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: maybe you need to do bundle install --deployment

Comment: I installed it as a plugin, w/out referencing it in the gemfile and it worked :)

Comment: sweet, bundler's meant to make things easier, but asking my hosts to install a gem was easier for me ;)